# Is there any way to reduce the decimal place from axis in plotly histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I have a histogram like this:

[image]

I want to remove the decimal place like it should be 0-50 instead of 0.0-50.0

This is my part of code:

```
fig = px.histogram(dataset, x=labels, y=hist[0],histnorm='percent')

fig.update_layout(bargap=0,title='Session per day',xaxis_title="salesperday", yaxis_title="% of Clinets")
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=1,marker_line_color="white",texttemplate='%{y:.2f}')



fig.show()
```

is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: YOU are providing the labels with `x=labels`, right?  It's completely under your control.

Comment: yes you are right!